# "Cannot allocate enough memory" error in Copy activity pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, hana

I am facing this error in the copy activity pipeline

```
Error code :2200

Failure type: User configuration issue
```

Details

> ErrorCode=SapHanaFailToGetBoundsDueToInvalidQuery,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Fail to get bounds by using query. Make sure your query can be nested while using partition reading and your partition column data type is acceptable.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapHanaConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [S1000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;4 cannot allocate enough memory:

**Where source**: Sap Hana
**Destination**: Adls

Query where condition is

```
WHERE ?AdfHanaDynamicRangePartitionCondition
```

Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-hana?tabs=data-factory

also In the dataset properties ,try to select in Quote character : **No quote character** option